# Is saying 'more confident' proper grammar?

Tags: word-choice

I am feeling confused about use of the word 'more' in front of adjectives, such as 'more confident'. Is the saying 'I am feeling more confident' grammatically correct? Or should it be 'I am feeling confident'?

I appreciate any input.

Thank you.

Comment: [Please look up: comparatives for adjectives of more than two syllables. This question will be closed here. It should be posted on ELL]

Comment: I don't think anybody has ever classified *confident* as a nongradable adjective, so *yes*.

Answer (score 1):

**Three syllable adjectives** can be used as a comparative by adding the word "more".

The child is **more confident** about this than the teacher.

- more confident than x
- more interesting than x
- more beautiful than x

etc.

[three syllable adjectives](https://eflnet.com/tutorials/adjcompsup#:%7E:text=For%20adjectives%20with%20three%20syllables,and%20the%20superlative%20with%20most.&text=John%20is%20more%20generous%20than,is%20more%20important%20than%20money.)

Answer (score 1):

"More confident" and "confident" have different meanings.  You use the first when making a comparison.  In this case the comparison is implied to mean

> *Now* I am feeling more confident *than I was feeling earlier*.

You understand the different meaning in this example:

> The tortoise walks slowly.

> The tortoise starting walking more quickly when it saw the lettuce leaf.

"more quickly" doesn't mean "quickly".